# Capture pid of a process started from a terminal with its unique command line

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, pid

I'm trying to get the process id of multiple processes run from a multiple tmux windows. Each processes started have their unique command line. I think only the command line is unique as there can be multiple processes with same name. what i did currently is

```
process_pid=$(ps --no-headers aux | grep "${process_cmd_line}" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' '')
```

This works for me. But i want to know if this is the correct approach to do this. I know there are output format specifiers. Any example to do the same with the format specifier or an improvement over the code above?

Comment: Why do you `tr` at the end? If there are multiple PIDs, they'll be concatenated.

Comment: since the command line is unique there should be only one process returned. tr is for removing the last new line

Comment: You might want to use the `pgrep` command instead of all that grepping.

Comment: You don't need to remove the last newline, that's done automatically by `$(...)`.

Comment: i did not know that. thanks. what about the original question? is this the right way to do this?

Comment: As I said, you can use `pgrep`, it's specifically designed for this.

Comment: how to pgrep a command with spaces in between?

Comment: `pgrep -f "$process_cmd_line"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If there is any other possible way to do this with only grep, ill be thankful. its just because the script is being targeted to some devices which has grep installed by default but no pgrep. it would be useful to avoid that dependency

Comment: In that case it looks like the usual idiom.